# How to filter a nested object and transform the resut at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filtering

I have a tree structure like this:

```json
const tree = [
    {
        slug: 'item-1',
        children: [
            {
                slug: 'item-1-1',
                children: [
                    { slug: 'item-1-1-1' },
                    { slug: 'item-1-1-2' }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        slug: 'item-2',
        children: [
            {
                slug: 'item-2-1',
                children: [
                    { slug: 'item-2-1-1' },
                    { slug: 'item-2-1-2' }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I want to filter it based on the `slug` which is not hard. I've seen some recursive solutions on StackOverflow. But I want only the direct children of the item to be in the result. For example, if I search for `slug === "item-1"`, the result should be:

```json
[
  {
    slug: "item-1"
    children: [
      slug: "item-1-1"
    ],
  },
]
```

Maybe I can combine `filter()` and `reduce()` or even `map()` and somehow solve this but it doesn't seem optimal. The tree is likely to be big and complex. How would you solve this?

Comment: Where is your attemps?

Comment: Once you've found the object, you can use map to remove the children's children: `foundObj.children = foundObj.children.map(({ slug }) => ({ slug }));`

Comment: `tree` is malformed

Comment: @GrafiCode what do you mean by malformed?

Comment: objects in your code are not correctly formatted

Comment: @ChrisG That's exactly what I want to avoid

Comment: @Mina I don't have access to the code base right now because I'm on my phone. But trust me, I've burned all of my brain cells before asking it here. I'm not much of an algorithm guy so I thought I can get more help from the right people.

Comment: Assuming the naming version is consistent, you don't actually have to filter.  You can instead build the object yourself. I.e. pull the values out of the string and then use that as an array call.   slug = tree[0].slug and then get tree[0].children.length to see how many items to put in the children array.

Comment: Your recursion function is going to have a line that returns the match. You can remove the children while returning the match, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xjL29ow8/ I still don't understand why this has to happen "at the same time" as finding the node, because that's not really possible anyway: you have to find the slug match first before you can remove the children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive approach. Basically, we are doing a breadth-first search, firstly we search at a level, and if the required item is found return the result after modifying the children array. If the key is not found in that level search the children.

```js
const tree = [
    {
        slug: 'item-1',
        children: [
            {
                slug: 'item-1-1',
                children: [{ slug: 'item-1-1-1' }, { slug: 'item-1-1-2' }],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        slug: 'item-2',
        children: [
            {
                slug: 'item-2-1',
                children: [{ slug: 'item-2-1-1' }, { slug: 'item-2-1-2' }],
            },
        ],
    },
];

const search = (data, key) => {
    if (!data?.length) return null;
    
    const children = [];

    let found = null;

    data.forEach((obj) => {
        if (obj.slug === key) {
            found = obj;
        }

        children.push(...(obj.children || []));
    });

    return found
        ? {
              slug: key,
              ...(found.children?.length && {
                  children: found.children.map(({ slug }) => ({ slug })),
              }),
          }
        : search(children, key);
};

console.log(search(tree, 'item-1-1'));
```